# White list load balancer in azure?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-service-fabric

I have a cluster in service fabric with an api gateway. This is going to be my entry point into my microservices. I have figured out how to allow/deny access to ports which secures the microservices but ideally I would like to only accept traffic from a specific IP address

This is a vm that is hosted in my azure account

Has anyone been able to do this?

Paul

Comment: You can try with NSG, it can set up a rule only accept the traffic from a specific IP address. Load Balancer just can balance the traffic.

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37658424/5946937 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633612/5946937 ?

Comment: Thanks I missed them. The first link looks promising but I am a bit confused why the solution states allow not deny the other link looks very complicated lol

Comment: @Paul You want to only accept the traffic from a specific IP address. So it's better to use "allow". If you use "deny", you should deny all the IP addresses except the specific IP address. It's difficult to do.